# Deserialize JSON non-standard numeric array

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to deserialize a JSON string. However, I am stuck in the non-standard structure: "000000001409026","000000001364365","869103022800595".

The numbers 000000001409026, 000000001364365, 869103022800595, are Id numbers of gps devices, so there may be one or multiple Id numbers in the JSON response. The file I get when making the query to the webservice using the RestSharp is the following:

```js
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "000000001409026": {
        "Fecha": "2018-01-26",
        "Kilometros": "84.17",
        "Odometro": "8,292.27",
        "Horas": "3.18"
      }
    },
    {
      "000000001364365": {
        "Fecha": "2018-01-26",
        "Kilometros": "0.00",
        "Odometro": "0.00",
        "Horas": "0.00"
      }
    },
    {
      "869103022800595": {
        "Fecha": "2018-01-26",
        "Kilometros": "0.00",
        "Odometro": "0.00",
        "Horas": "0.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The class that I am using is the following:

```js
public class GpsOdometro
    {
       public string Fecha { get; set; }
       public string Kilometros { get; set; }
       public string Odometro { get; set; }
       public string  Horas { get; set; }
    }

    public class GpsEquipo
    {
        public Dictionary<string,GpsOdometro> GpsOdometro { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<GpsEquipo> data { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I deserialize the json obtained but when I want to show it in a datagridview, the data is not shown.

```js
IRestResponse json = client.Execute(request);
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.Content);
DgOdometro.DataSource = result.data;
```

I need help to properly handle this json structure and get the gps data.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you re-construct your de-serialized  object into a flat object and bind it to gridview?

Comment: have you checked that deserialization indeed produced a valid object? if the answer is yes, than there is no problem with json itself, problem might be somewhere on a data -> UI rendering procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`DeserializeObject` icreates 3 lists in `data`, however the dictionaries in those lists are `null`. You can grab the data from the json to fill them one by one

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.Content);
JToken dataToken = JObject.Parse(json.Content).SelectToken("data");
int i = 0;
foreach (JProperty property in dataToken.Children().SelectMany(child => ((JObject)child).Properties()))
{
    result.data[i++].GpsOdometro =
        new Dictionary<string, GpsOdometro>
        {
            { property.Name, JObject.Parse(o2.ToString()).SelectToken(property.Path).ToObject<GpsOdometro>() }
        };
}
```